# \n in return statement of function prints \n instead of new line in python

Tags: python

Consider the below python code.I am very new to python.Please help me with this.
this function returns 
'\n56' 
but i need 
--new line--
56

```
def fun_ret(num):
    return '\n'+str(num)
if __name__=='__main__':
    a=fun_ret(56)
```

I have gone through similar posts but it was all about print statement

Actual scenario is to pass the doctest of method **str** in a class.

```
def __str__(self):
    """(Maze)-->str
    The parameter represents a maze. Return a string representation of the maze 
    >>> maze=Maze([['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],['#', 'J', '.', '.', 'P', '.', '#'], ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'],['#', '.', '.', '@', '#', '.', '#'],['#', '@', '#', '.', '@', '.', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']], Rat('J', 1, 1),Rat('P', 1, 4))
    >>> str(maze)
    "#######
    #J..P.#
    #.###.#
    #..@#.#
    #@#.@.#
    #######
    J at (1, 1) ate 0 sprouts.
    P at (1, 4) ate 0 sprouts."
    """
    result=''
    for outer_list in self.maze_content:
        for inner_list in outer_list:
            result +='{0}'.format(str(inner_list))
        result+='\n'
    result += '\n'+'{0} at ({1}, {2}) ate {3} sprouts.'.format(self.rat_1.symbol,self.rat_1.row,self.rat_1.col,self.rat_1.num_sprouts_eaten)
    result += '\n'+('{0} at ({1}, {2}) ate {3} sprouts.'.format(self.rat_2.symbol,self.rat_2.row,self.rat_2.col,self.rat_2.num_sprouts_eaten))
    return result


if __name__=='__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: You can't,  you're specifying a string literal. Nothing in your code attempts to actually display the result.

Comment: you are specifically returning `\n` in your function

Comment: This is not printing *anything*. And it *returns* indeed such a string, there is a difference between the *content* of a string, and its representation.

Comment: how can i return new line

Comment: ... You did already. What is a newline if it's not printed?

Comment: Only return the number.
If you want to print it, use `print(var)` elsewhere in your code. Every print statement writes a new line. If you want multiple lines within your print, then use "\n" inside it like `print(a, "\n", b)`

Comment: That doctest is your Gandalf. You shall not pass. (The representation of a string does not display newlines as new lines.)

Answer (score 5):

Are you working in a line-oriented command shell?  If so, I can see your confusion.  A typical command shell has a special routine for simply displaying a variable value, one that does *not* convert output formatting characters.  For instance, the default Python interactive shell gives us this:

```
>>> def fun_ret(num):
...     return '\n'+str(num)
... 
>>> a=fun_ret(56)
>>> a
'\n56'
>>> print(a)

56
>>>
```

Note the difference: the simple `a` command carefully displays the *string* value of the variable, expanding the visual short-hand for various control characters.  The `print` command applies the standard formatter, which is where the `\n` character is turned into an actual "new line" operation.

Does that help clear up the problem?

Comment: They can't be? `if __name__=='__main__':` I can't test; does that work in REPL? They already broke out of the function body so it would just have executed?

Comment: The same may happen in a notebook environment (happened to me in vs code)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question at this point but I found it while trying to solve a similar problem myself (I was doing a challenge in a course I was taking in which I had to print a string containing multiple lines out of a dictionary of strings).  So, since some of the comments lead me to my answer, I'd like to share it here in case someone else has the same problem later.

Instead of just returning the string, as in OP's case:

```py
    def fun_ret(num):
        return '\n'+str(num)
```

you can print the statement, like so:

```py
    def fun_ret(num):
        print('\n'+str(num))
```

This wouldn't necessarily work if you potentially need to return that function into just a variable somewhere, in which case you'd probably be better off using the first definition, but calling it in a print statement:

```
    print(fun_ret(num))
```

instead.

I'm not sure if this will help with the actual situation specified by OP (pretty new to Python myself), but it will cause the function call to print a new line, rather than just return the value, if that's what someone needs for their use case.

Comment: This is incorrect, the `fun_ret` function is not returning a print statement, it is returning `None` after printing a newline and then the number.  You can see this by looking at the difference between `fun_ret(10)` and `print(fun_ret(10))`, the latter prints `None` after printing `10`

Comment: Interesting, that makes sense. I'm currently wondering why I didn't just have the function print the line and not return, but since I haven't touched that code in over a year I can't answer that at this point. :)

Comment: Finally got around to modifying the code based on @asm 's comment, it should be more accurate now.